# python process is being terminated even with try except

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, mqtt, raspberry-pi4

I have a raspberry pi 4 which is being used as a apache and mqtt server and I have written a python script as the radio and mqtt handler, the script starts 4 separate processes at the beginning:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
proc1 = Process(target=mqttClient.loop_forever)
proc1.start()
proc2 = Process(target=receive)
proc2.start()
proc3 = Process(target=routineLoop)
proc3.start()
proc4 = Process(target=serverLoop)
proc4.start()
```

each of the functions have a true while and should be running all the time and codes in each loop surrendered by try except for example the receive function is like this:

```
def receive():
global radio
radioConfigTime = time.time()
logTime = time.time()
while(1):
    try:
        if time.time()-logTime >= 30:
            logTime = time.time()
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            rlog(str(current_time))
        receivedMessage = []
        radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
        string = ""
        enterTime = time.time()
        for n in receivedMessage:
            if time.time()-enterTime>=5:
                enterTime = time.time()
                rlog("in for loop for "+str(n))
            if (n >= 12 and n <= 126):
                string += chr(n)
        if string[0:3]=="ABC":
            function = "sendABC"
            repairPARAMS = {'function':function,'id':string[0:10]}
            req = requests.get(url = sqliteURL, params = repairPARAMS, verify=False)
    except Exception as e:
        rlog(str(e))
        print("receive exception happened.")
```

as you can see in the code I'm writing timestamps into a file as logs (using rlog function) to see how long the script will work.
the problem is the receive function (loop) after about a day (the last time was about 26 hours) just stops working and timestamp not being printed anymore and also no log is being printed as the exception message while all other functions working just fine although all of the functions have a true while surrendered by try except.
So anyone knows how can I fix this problem? also sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Why call `loop_forever()` in it's own process, when you could just call `loop_start()` and the client will run it's own loop on a separate thread?

Comment: And by "Apache" do you really mean HTTP? And a MQTT client  (not a broker)

Comment: yes you are right I can just call loop_start instead of starting proc1 and I will change that but mqttClient loop is working just fine and the problem occurs in receive loop.

Comment: yes exactly a http apache server and a mqtt client